# Loading a bulk of device tokens into SNS using Boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto, amazon-sns, boto3

I need to upload new device tokens to AWS SNS, and would rather doing it in batches instead of one token at a time.

According to the AWS documentation this is supported by their API, and an example is given for [the Java SDK](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/mobile-push-send-devicetoken.html) using a "bulkupload package".

The problem is that I wrote everything in Python and I can't find any reference to this feature in the Boto3 documentation.

Do you know of a way to do this in Python (not necessarily using Boto)? Or am I doomed to either uploading tokens one by one or rewrite everything in Java?

Thanks!

Comment: the java version is basically just putting threading and a queue around the requests- it doesn't call anything boto3 doesn't have access to. You can see that in CreateEndpointJob.java around line 108.

Comment: That's unfortunate... Thanks!